# How to get button path for click event in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

Having problems generating a click event for a button using python 3:

```
<div align="left"><input type="button" value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS" onclick="javascript:doarea(2)" style="width:400px;height:70px;fontsize:18px;font-weight:bold;color:blue"></div>
```

I tried this-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="main"]/h2[2]/div/input')).click();
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: <div align="left">
  <input type="button" value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS" onclick="javascript:doarea(2)" style="width:400px;height:70px;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:blue">
 </div>

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your HTML document, so it's possible to validate whether the xpath is correct.

Comment: <h2>Account balance <span>10.9</span> $<b><font style="font-size:14px;"></font></b> <input type="button" value="Refresh" onclick="javascript:doarea(1)"><br><br>
 <br>
 <div align="left">
  <input type="button" value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS" onclick="javascript:doarea(2)" style="width:400px;height:70px;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:blue">
 </div>
 <br><br>

 </h2>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *HTML* you have shared, to click on the *button* with *value* as **START WATCHING PAYED AD** you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='START WATCHING PAYED ADS' and @type='button']").click()
```

---

### Update

As you are seeing *NoSuchElementException* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@value='START WATCHING PAYED ADS' and @type='button']"))).click()
```

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@value='START WATCHING PAYED ADS' and @type='button']"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.39.562718 (9a2698cba08cf5a471a29d30c8b3e12becabb0e9),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)

Comment: @harsh Check out the answer update, of-coarse the `<input>` tag have an attribute **type="button"**

Answer (score -1):

Please refer https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html
for basic xpath knowledge.

It's better not to use an index when identifying the element, you can for example do it with below query

```
*//input[@value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS"]
```

Comment: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression *//input[@value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '*//input[@value="START WATCHING PAYED ADS"' is not a valid XPath expression.